# R: save the shapefile IDs in a particular order as a vector

Tags: r, raster, shapefile, rgdal

Sample data

```
      library(raster)
      dat <- getData('GADM', country='FRA', level=1)
      plot(dat)
      text(dat, labels=as.character(dat$ID_1), col="darkred", font=2, offset=0.5, adj=c(0,2))
```

[image]

To save the IDs of provinces, I can do this

```
      province.id <- dat$ID_1
```

However, I want to arrange these IDs according to some direction (i.e. south to north)

For example, my `province.id` id should start from 10 (since it is the southern most province) all the way till 17 since it is the northern most province 
One way I thought was I can generate centorid of each province and based on the centroid,
I can determine which are the most south to most north location.

```
      library(rgeos)
      trueCentroids = gCentroid(dat,byid=TRUE)
      plot(dat)
      points(coordinates(dat),pch=1)
```

[image]

But I still cannot export the output or arrange the centroids in the south-to-north direction
to save as a vector

Comment: What about `dat$ID_1[order(coordinates(dat)[,2])]` ?

Comment: Okay. This is quite simple. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy approach would be to take the minimum latitude of each polygon and sort your IDs based on that:

```
# data 

library(raster)
dat <- getData('GADM', country='FRA', level=1)

# create south to north index
sn_index <- unlist(lapply(dat@polygons, function(x) min(x@Polygons[[1]]@coords[,2])))

#sort IDs

dat$ID_1[order(sn_index)]
# [1] 10 13 21 16 22  3  2 14 20  6 18  8 11  7  1  9 15  4  5 19 12 17
```

Comment: This gives a slighty different order than what  Michael suggested in the comments using `dat$ID_1[order(coordinates(dat)[,2])]` I wonder why this difference between the two approaches?

Comment: Michael uses the centroids ... my approach uses the minimum latitude of the polygons

Comment: Okay. I guess both of these approaches are suited to my needs. Thank you